# Is there any collision related topic in ign gazebo?

Tags: collision, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone, I wanna test some collision properties and I have found the contact topic in classical gazebo as below:
[image: image description]
but I didn't find any similar topic in ign gazebo, does anyone have some experience in testing collision in ign gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28008/is-there-any-collision-related-topic-in-ign-gazebo?/) by [hang_R](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/80775/hang_r/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-04-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2022-04-13**:
what do you see when you type `ign topic -l`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

solved. There is a topic called ‘sensor/sensor_contact/contact’

---

Originally posted by [hang_R](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/80775/hang_r/) with karma: 1 on 2022-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2022-04-14**:
Nice!! Let's go!

Could you mark this as solved so others can find the same solution if they had the same question as you?